# Module build failed: provided an invalid property of "__wrapped__"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-google-maps

The react module in question is ["react-google-maps"](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps), but I guess this is more of a general issue on how to install, uninstall packages.

I have installed this component using  the command:

```
npm install --save react-google-maps
```

Like it recommends on their github.

I after start my webpack server by doing:

```
webpack-dev-server --env.dev --open --watch --progress --colors
```

Everything works fine, but then I shut the server and start it again, with the same command, and that's when I get the error.

> Module build failed: provided an invalid property of "**wrapped**"

If I try to uninstall it and install it again the same error appears, after restarting the server.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is excluding /node_modules/ from loading.
You have to add `exclude: /node_modules/` to your webpack config.